# C#.NET Using isAuthenticated

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Im using the MVC format to create a website. Right now all it does is manage users from an SQL server. What i'm trying to do now is have the user log in and then be able to manage the Users. From the Login page it should go to the Index of the Account but I only want this page to be viewable by authenticated users. It works fine if I:

1)set the function in the controler to [AllowAnonymous] (This is not what i want)

2)Allow Windows Authentication (Which is not what I want because once I deploy, it'll be on the web)

It really just boils down to how do I authenticate a user and then have that authentication persist.

Here is the login page:

```
@model myWebsite.Models.LoginModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Login";
    ViewBag.ReturnUrl = "Index";
}

<h2>Login</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Login", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Login</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger"})
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(Model => Model.UserName, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2"})
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.UserName, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label"})
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Model => Model.UserName, "" , new { @class = "text-danger"})
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(Model => Model.Password, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2"})
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(Model => Model.Password, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label"})
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Model => Model.Password, "" , new { @class = "text-danger"})
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Log In" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

This is the partial portion of every page

```
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;

@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm", @class = "navbar-right" }))
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Hello "  + User.Identity.GetUserName() + "!", "Index" , "Manage", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage" } )</li>
        </ul>
    }
}
else
{
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Register", "Create", "Login", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "registerLink" })</li>
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Log in", "Login", "Login", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { id = "loginLink" })</li>
    </ul>
}
```

This is the controller

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    // GET: Login
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }


    [AllowAnonymous]
    // GET: Login
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string retunUrl)
    {

        /* 
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("IS NOT VALID");
            return View(model);
        }
       */
        String UserName = model.UserName;
        String Password = model.Password;

        LoginContext LC = new LoginContext();
        LoginModel ValidUser = LC.UserList.Single(Person => Person.UserName == UserName && Person.Password == Password);

        if (ValidUser != null)
        {
            return Redirect("Index");
        }
        return View(model);
    }




    // GET: Login Index of users
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.UserList.ToList());
    }
```

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Comment: No where are you authenticating your user in the Login() method. Suggest you create a new MVC project and study the code that VS creates for you. And go to the MVC site and read the section on [Security, Authentication and Authorization](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security)

Comment: It's also worth mentioning somewhere whether this application is using OWIN or not - the methods available change slightly if you are.

Comment: I'm fairly new to this ASP.NET as a whole and some what new to C#... @TiesonT So to be honest I have no idea. Although I have not checked or explicitly imported OWIN

Comment: @StephenMuecke Sorry for the mistakes I made in writing this post. Im still getting used to this forum. As for checking what VS uses to authenticate, it is quite in depth and one day I want to understand what it does entirely but for now most of what is done in those class are beyond my understanding and I would really rather understand, instead of copying code and getting it to work but having no real idea as to what has been written.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### The Old Way™

If all you care about is persisting the fact that a user gave you valid credentials, your simplest option is probably FormsAuthentication:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, false);
```

and

```
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
```

These require that the FormsAuthentication module is active, so you would look for a line like this in the web.config:

```
<remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
```

and remove it, and either add or update the authentication section:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/account/login" timeout="2880" defaultUrl="~/" protection="All" />
</authentication>
```

With these settings, ASP.NET knows to build the Identity and Principle from the cookie generated by `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie`.

#### The Right(ish) Way™

That being said, FormsAuthentication is not the recommended path at this point, both for it's reliance on System.Web, and the fact that it isn't claims aware.

You can accomplish a minimum setup using OWIN that does yield a claims-aware Identity. If you started with a newer ASP.NET project template, you should have a Startup.Auth.cs file in the App_Start folder, or you can add one. The minimum code to use cookie-based authentication with OWIN is:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
using Owin;

public partial class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            LoginPath = new PathString("/account/login"),
            LogoutPath = new PathString("/account/logout"),
            CookieName = ".YOUR_COOKIE_NAME_HERE",
            SlidingExpiration = true, 
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            AuthenticationMode = AuthenticationMode.Active
        });
    }
}
```

Then, when you authenticate your user, you do something like:

```
var claims = new List<Claim>();
claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, model.UserName));

var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
HttpContext.Current.Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignIn(identity);
```

And to sign out:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
```

You will also need to set the following value in your Global.asax file:

```
using System.Web.Helpers;
using System.Security.Claims;

public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        // ... your other startup/registration code ...

        AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier = ClaimTypes.Name;
    }
}
```

The `Request.IsAuthenticated` just checks to see if a non-anonymous Identity has been established on the current request context, so either option noted above will work.

**As an aside:** *you really should not be storing passwords in plain text.* When you create your user records, use `Crypto.HashPassword` to create a salted hash of the password, storing that instead, and then use `Crypto.VerifyHashedPassword` when checking if the user entered the correct password. You can find the [Crypto documentation here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.crypto.aspx).

Comment: Your "Rightish" solution worked but now i'm getting an error: "A claim of type 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier' or 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/accesscontrolservice/2010/07/claims/identityprovider' was not present on the provided ClaimsIdentity". I tried changing the the antiforgery claim type with the line: AntiForgeryConfig.UniqueClaimTypeIdentifier = ClaimTypes.Name; but i still receive the error. Removing the Antiforgery token works (not surprisingly) but the more I read about it makes it seem that its a good practie to use.

Comment: @Hippiewho Sorry, you were correct - I left part of the answer out. See edit. Other than that setting, I am using more or less the same code in a current project, with no errors.

Comment: "You will also need to set the following value in your Global.asax file:" Okay, cool.. WHERE?  Thanks.

Comment: @ScottK.Fraley `Application_Start`, normally. I've updated that bit.