# ASP.Net MVC, "Register" Link in Loginform always redirecting to Loginpage

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-authorization

I built a simple loginpage with an ActionLink that should redirect me to the Register Page.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register", "Account", null, new { @class = "page-scroll" })
```

But whenever I click the ActionLink, I get redirected to the LoginPage.

This is probably because of my web.config file denying any users and redirecting to the Loginpage.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

How can I allow users to access Login + Register Page? Also for later on, what is the best way to give different users different access to each View?
Example User1 is allowed to Edit and View Data, User2 is only allowed to View data?

Thank you!

EDIT: Controller added

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginModel login)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (login.IsValid(login.UserName,login.Passwort))
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(login.UserName, login.RememberMe);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            else
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username or password.");
        }
        return View(login);  // Fehler, wieder anzeigen
    }


    public ActionResult Register()
    {
        return View();
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Register(LoginModel model)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                movieEntities db = new movieEntities();
                var newUser = db.users.Create();
                var encrypPass = Helpers.SHA256.Encode(model.Passwort);
                var user = model.UserName;
                newUser.user_name = user;
                newUser.user_passwdhash = encrypPass;
                db.users.Add(newUser);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
        {
            foreach (var eve in e.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Entity of type \"{0}\" in state \"{1}\" has the following validation errors:",
                    eve.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name, eve.Entry.State);
                foreach (var ve in eve.ValidationErrors)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("- Property: \"{0}\", Error: \"{1}\"",
                        ve.PropertyName, ve.ErrorMessage);
                }
            }
            throw;
        }
        return View(model);
    }

    public ActionResult LogOff()
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
}
```

Filter config:

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    }
}
```

Comment: Would be helpful to see how your controller is setup - most likely, you have an `[Authorize]` attribute on the controller and you haven't added the `[AllowAnonymous]` attribute on the Register action.

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for your replies! I havent set "Authorized" or "AllowAnonymous" Attributes. Should I update my post anyways and show you the controller?

Comment: Yes. Probably help to see your FilterConfig as well. And yes, you probably shouldn't be using that authorization setting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see anything there that looks like an issue, so it's most likely that `<authorization>` tag in your web.config - you don't normally use that, except to secure specific assets (like `elmah.axd`, for instance, assuming you used ELMAH), when using the MVC framework. If you want to automatically secure everything, add the AuthorizationAttribute to your global filters:

```cs
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
        filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());
    }
}
```

Then your controller would look something like this:

```cs
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login(LoginModel login)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (login.IsValid(login.UserName,login.Passwort))
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(login.UserName, login.RememberMe);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            else
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid username or password.");
        }
        return View(login);  // Fehler, wieder anzeigen
    }


    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Register()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Register(LoginModel model)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                movieEntities db = new movieEntities();
                var newUser = db.users.Create();
                var encrypPass = Helpers.SHA256.Encode(model.Passwort);
                var user = model.UserName;
                newUser.user_name = user;
                newUser.user_passwdhash = encrypPass;
                db.users.Add(newUser);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException e)
        {
            foreach (var eve in e.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Entity of type \"{0}\" in state \"{1}\" has the following validation errors:",
                    eve.Entry.Entity.GetType().Name, eve.Entry.State);
                foreach (var ve in eve.ValidationErrors)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("- Property: \"{0}\", Error: \"{1}\"",
                        ve.PropertyName, ve.ErrorMessage);
                }
            }
            throw;
        }
        return View(model);
    }

    public ActionResult LogOff()
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
}
```

As an aside, since you're just starting to build this, you may want to look into Claims-based authorization, which is a bit more flexible than FormsAuthentication.

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly! Will Claims-based authorization solve my problem with allowing for different users to view different content?

Comment: Claims-based auth works similar to forms auth, except that you generally move from "roles" to "user X can perform action Y". If you use the Role claim, you can even just keep using things like User.IsInRole without needing to implement Membership and it's associated providers.

Comment: @ConstantinM If you want a bare-bones suggestion for claims, I added [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38193377/c-net-using-isauthenticated/38215903#38215903) a while back.